# Error in using Lowe's SIFT Matlab program on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, matlab, sift, binaries

I'm trying to use David Lowe's Matlab demo of SIFT in Matlab on my Mac.

But I'm constantly getting the error:

```
[image, desc, locations] = sift('book.pgm')
/bin/bash: ./sift: cannot execute binary file
Error using sift (line 57)
Invalid keypoint file beginning.
```

I have executed the makefile, but the problem persists.

Note: I'm using Matlab 8.4.0.

Really appreciate any help! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not matlab problem.
The sift version shipped to you is not intended for use on OSX.
you can assure that by running 
`file sift`

The result most likely will be:

`sift: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, not stripped`

Just stumbled across your question while solving the same problem - Matlab, Lowe's SIFT and OSX.

The original files from Lowe (http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/keypoints/siftDemoV4.zip) do not have OSX version. Only Linux/Win.

Currently i see 2 possible paths to solution:

- <s>compile Lowe's sift for OSX</s> (searching for a while shows that source is tightly bound to linux/win)
- try a replacement. Like [vlfeat](http://www.vlfeat.org/), [OpenSIFT](http://robwhess.github.io/opensift/) or [siftGPU](http://cs.unc.edu/~ccwu/siftgpu/) and rewriting MATLAB wrapper code.

Keep in mind that using external bin for generating a key file (it's used this way all through MATLAB) requires to check the key file format correspondence. ([vlfeat to Lowe's SIFT](http://blog.aradine.com/2010/10/converting-vlfeat-sift-output-to-lowe.html))